# Not able to access mobile site even after changing the user-agent string in pc browser

Tags: mobile, user-agent, mozilla

[hrmantra](https://www.hrmantra.com)
is the site i want to view mobile view of. For which i have also changed my user-agent string in my pc's mozilla browser. I need this to be done, please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Responsive Design Mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_Mode) tool in Firefox to [pick a mobile phone configuration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_Mode#Device_selection) or create a new one with custom settings. You can access this tool, as reported on the provided links:

> From the Firefox menu: select "Responsive Design Mode" from the Web
>   Developer submenu in the Firefox Menu (or Tools menu if you display
>   the menu bar or are on OS X).

Picking a mobile device will automatically set the correct screen resolution, user-agent string and device pixel ratio (DPR).

Comment: you can see for yourself.. this would just change the resolution... however it just renders the pc website not the mobile version of it...